# How to decode a bytes value from Ethereum event with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, events, bytes, decoding

I've got the following event declaration in my Solidity contract:

```
    event RemoteOrderCreated(bytes32 indexed id, uint32 indexed nonce, address indexed sender, bytes input);
```

And I capture the event like so:

```js
contract.on('eventName', async (...args) => {
  // here I have all the event args
})
```

For this sample transaction [(sepolia block explorer link)](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xc032fde6dae43075c5cdd5f6033866279ade7e3cd44aae6d87e3af0872a0e329) the `args` looks like this:

```json
[
  '0x1ae0b4b1df473f1aea6c8970adf5347aa0eaf656ba1c6888e4876c889488ef18',
  4502989,
  '0xCbeeBE266ab8d734a8ccd90097bF87809893977B',
  '0x030303030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a'
]
```

Value at index 0 is the `id` from the event, at index 1 is the `nonce`, at index 2 is the `sender` and at index 3 is the `input` prop.

This is the part of the ABI relating to the event declaration:

```json
{
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "MyContract",
  "sourceName": "contracts/MyContract.sol",
  "abi": [
    {
      "inputs": [
        // inputs
      ],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    // HERE is the event declaraion:
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "bytes32",
          "name": "id",
          "type": "bytes32"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "uint32",
          "name": "nonce",
          "type": "uint32"
        },
        {
          "indexed": true,
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "sender",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "bytes",
          "name": "input",
          "type": "bytes"
        }
      ],
      "name": "RemoteOrderCreated",
      "type": "event"
    },
    // the rest of the ABI
 ]
}
```

I need to decode the `input`, but I'm not being successful.
I tried with `ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode()` in different combinations of: providing the contract ABI, or just specific parts of it (relating to the event itself), and the `input` value that I want to decode.

I also tried with simple bytes decoding, but to no avail.

Is there a standard way of decoding bytes values from events/transactions?

Comment: You just need to provide the correct data structure for your bytes input part. Right now a complete guess is there are:

Some identifier: `0x03030303`
Some zero value.
Some possibly uint256 value: `1000` in dec.
Some other identifier or some data: `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d`.
Some other uint256 value: `10` in dec.

You need to tell ethers what these are. If you can share the source code, I can have a look.

Comment: Hey @Ake, I've just updated the post, adding the ABI relating to the event declaration. Is that what you asked for? If not, can you be more specific about what you mean by "source code" - which part exactly?

Comment: Hi! To decode the input, you need to know what the smart contract function that emits the event looks like. Do you have the code of the function? from there you can see what the input looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thru a bunch of research I found out that when it's not a specific type of `bytes` type, eg. `bytes4` or `bytes32` etc..., but just `bytes`, then you need to figure out what is the structure of the encoded bytes string.

In my case, it's the following:

```
(bytes4, uint32, bytes32, uint256, address, uint256, uint256)
```

I got that from the Solidity contract where the `input` is being encoded before emitted with the event.

So, the JS solution is as follows:

```js
decodedInput = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(
  ['bytes4', 'uint32', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'address', 'uint256', 'uint256'],
  input
)
```